# Postgres cannot cast type jsonb to integer

Tags: json, postgresql, join

Threre are two tables.

Table1

```
 id integer
 color_name character(64)
```

Table2

```
 id integer
 jdata jsonb
```

Json data looks like:

```
{"price": 4500, "colorId": 5}
```

I need output colors and count of items grouped by colors, so i tried to use this query:

```
SELECT Table1.color_name, Table2.jdata ->> 'colorId', count(*)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.jdata ->> 'colorId'
group by Table2.jdata ->> 'colorId';
```

I get an error:

> error: operator does not exist: integer = jsonb

Also i tried exec this:

```
select Table1.color_name, count(*) 
from Table1
join Table2
on (Table2.jdata->>'colorId')::int = Table1.id
group by Table1.color_name
```

What i get:

> error: cannot cast type jsonb to integer

Comment: Show minimal sample data and then expected output

Comment: Which database version are you using?

Comment: Note, this appears to have been fixed in Postgres 11.

Answer (score 13):

I think you need this:

```
select Table1.color_name, count(*) 
from Table1
join Table2
on (Table2.jdata->>'colorId')::int = Table1.id
group by Table1.color_name
```

Comment: Thanks! But new error happened: "error: cannot cast type jsonb to integer"

Comment: @КириллТабельский This works very well with Postgres 9.4 and higher: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=dc62446656d437aeb32e6714ca641be4

Comment: @КириллТабельский - Are you sure you use `->>` operator instead of `->` ?

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this?

Comment: @Shayne it works for me if you use `(col ->> 'field')::integer` but it seems it goes via text so it's a bit slow. There's a patch to go directly from jsonb to numeric:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9c013081-5dc0-1b87-a559-a0c2d405727a%40postgrespro.ru

Comment: Can anyone tell me the exact version of Postgres that this (casting from jsonb to int) was fixed in? From my testing, it works fine in Postgres 10.14, but not in 9.6.18, but I'd like to know more specifically.

Answer (score 7):

Simple way to resolve this problem: `select cast(value #>> '{}' as integer)`

'value' is variable jsonb type.

For instance:

```
select  cast(to_jsonb('3'::text) #>> '{}' as integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Context**: Casting `jsonb` to `int` is not working properly.

**Solution**: Try going to other way around. if you try to match `int` to `jsonb` you'll still get an error, so you may try this:

```
SELECT Table1.color_name, count(*) 
  FROM Table1
    JOIN Table2 ON Table2.jdata->'colorId' = Table1.id::text::jsonb
  GROUP BY Table1.color_name
```

Comment: Worked for me in Postgres 10:  
`select * from MyTable where i."JsonbColumn" -> 'total' > '1000000'::jsonb;`